# Programmatic way to stop roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw in the description of roslaunch this:
*"roslaunch is an important tool that manages the start and stop of ROS nodes"*
But I am not able to find how to stop a roslaunch.
Is there any method to kill all nodes of a roslaunch in one instructions?

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10493/programmatic-way-to-stop-roslaunch/) by [smerino](https://answers.ros.org/users/675/smerino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ctrl-C works.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-18**:
You can also pass the SIGINT to whatever subprocess handle you started it with in code.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"rosnode kill -a"

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for this answers, but for me it is not a solution because it is another node which launch the roslaunch, and of course there are other nodes, so I cannot kill all nodes with kill.
Another idea?

---

Originally posted by [smerino](https://answers.ros.org/users/675/smerino/) with karma: 108 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-05**:
Yes, sending SIGINT/Ctrl-C should kill roslaunch, which will kill the launched nodes.

**Comment by [smerino](https://answers.ros.org/users/675/smerino/) on 2011-09-04**:
The problem is that I don't know which are the nodes that the laucher will run. So, if I kill the launcher process, the nodes will be killed?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-16**:
For the current node you can just use getpid(). According to the problem of smerino it depends on how you start it.

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-07-16**:
@dornhege:  How?  I see there is a ros::kill(__pid_t __pid, int __sig), but how do you invoke this from within the code. I mean, how do you know the pid_t of the current node?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-06**:
Can you describe what the intention of that is? You might be doing something more complicated than necessary. Anyways, you can still insert a Ctrl-C/SIGINT into a running process/roslaunch via the kill command.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the python api exposes a method for stopping a roslaunch

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-18**:
But that is just for a single node?  Maybe if that could take a ros package name and `.launch` file parameter, and then launch and later kill the whole thing and all child nodes like ctrl-c does, that would be great, though @smerino wants to kill a launch file started elsewhere.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-24**:\

> that is just for a single node?

@lucasw Not sure where you got that impression. [ROSLaunchParent.shutdown](http://docs.ros.org/api/roslaunch/html/roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent-class.html#shutdown) seems to be able to kill the launch process.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-09-25**:
Probably it was the documentation that was online at that time: http://wiki.ros.org/action/recall/roslaunch/API%20Usage?action=recall&rev=2 there isn't a mention of launch files.  I think the launch file capability existed for some time prior to being documented, then in lunar argument support.

**Comment by [Gushu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33421/gushu/) on 2019-05-22**:
legend. Works well from a simple python script.

**Comment by [byteofprash](https://answers.ros.org/users/59401/byteofprash/) on 2020-12-09**:
While this works fine in stopping the process, I however am not able to restart the launch file again using .spin()
I get an error saying that

```
pm is not initialized
```

Anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless the scriptapi actually can run launch files, here is my (somewhat confusing) solution.

1. Create a node that uses scriptapi to start/stop a single node specified by params. (the scriptapi approach doesn't look like it can run launch files, just nodes- it is just a programmatic rosrun, not roslaunch?)
2. Create a node that uses roslaunch directly to start a param defined launch file, with a hack to get around the way roslaunch uses sys.argv.  The main method blocks so doesn't have a nice start/stop/is_alive interface like scriptapi.

   ```
    sys.agv=['roslaunch', 'pkg_name', 'foo.launch', 'arg:=bar']
    import roslaunch
    roslaunch.main(args)
   ```
3. Start the second roslaunch raw node within the first scriptapi node, and then if the stop method is used it uses the scriptapi stop method which interrupts the roslaunch, kills all the child nodes as desired.

Maybe there is an idea to allow scriptapi to run launch files, but it isn't currently implemented: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/scriptapi.py#L74

This question is similar to http://answers.ros.org/question/223090/start-or-stop-the-ros-node-in-another-node/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/203154/is-it-possible-to-run-and-quit-launch-files-from-code-inside-a-node/

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-12-07**:
is `subprocess` of python an alternative solution for this?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-12-07**:
Probably, but I'd like to leverage ros tools as much as possible- it seems like they almost support this but for now I'm using the above multi-stage technique.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-19**:
It looks like lunar and beyond python roslaunch supports roslaunch arguments http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage#Roslaunch_file_with_command_line-style_arguments (my hacky solution is a way to get arguments in), in that example `parent.stop()` would stop the launch.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using C++ you can use `system("pkill roslaunch")` in your node to kill the roslaunch from the system level.  I use it for monte carlo simulations with Gazebo).

---

Originally posted by [superjax](https://answers.ros.org/users/20144/superjax/) with karma: 51 on 2016-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My suggestion would be to rely on one or several nodes to take down the whole roslaunch script when they finish executing. Use the `required="true"` attribute inside a `<node>` tag, so whenever your node dies or finishes it takes down all of the other nodes in the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [jpiramirez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2480/jpiramirez/) with karma: 141 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-12-05**:
This looks like a good idea, but may not suit for situation of Start and Stop .launch file.

**Comment by [katzuv](https://answers.ros.org/users/45532/katzuv/) on 2019-12-11**:
Just tried this solution, it works. Probably the best and most simple answer in this thread.
You can find the documentation for this attribute (and others) here: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes

**Comment by [EnriqueSolarte](https://answers.ros.org/users/117937/enriquesolarte/) on 2022-09-15**:
It works for me. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend you to use the `subprocess` module to solve this problem.
e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import subprocess
import signal

child = subprocess.Popen(["roslaunch","ros_arduino_python","arduino.launch"])
#child.wait() #You can use this line to block the parent process untill the child process finished.
print("parent process")
print(child.poll())

rospy.loginfo('The PID of child: %d', child.pid)
print ("The PID of child:", child.pid)

rospy.sleep(15)

child.send_signal(signal.SIGINT) #You may also use .terminate() method
#child.terminate()

#for more: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
```

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on 2017-06-22**:
does it work on ros kinetic as well. Till now i am not able to execute above script successfully on ros kinetic version. it looks like in below code second argument is rospackage and 3rd one is name of launch file.

roslaunch","ros_arduino_python","arduino.launch"]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to stop it in the command line, you can kill the process like this:

```
roslaunch [package] [launchfile] &
roslaunch_PID=$!
# Do whatever you need to do here
kill -INT $roslaunch_PID
```

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1